# XML Schema Validation Tools in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, validation, xsd, schema

I'd like to know if there is an online solution for validating XML files when having a Schema, like an .xsd file. By online, I mean we should not sent our xml files to a (possibly unknown) server to be validated server side. Any suggestions for complete online solutions?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://syssgx.github.com/xml.js/)? First google result for "javascript validate xml schema."

Comment: @DaggNabbit I tried googling that exact phrase and this is the page I'm directed to..

Comment: That's because I wrote it here. Try without quotes =p